# Broken Pipe error deploying on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I've trying to deploy a rails app on Heroku, but I'm getting a rare error `"broken pipe"`.

log:

```
Write failed: Broken pipe/25742), 304.00 KiB | 6 KiB/s    
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:*****.git'
```

The only different thing I'm doing compared to other developments I have made on Heroku is that I'm loading a specific gem from the vendor folder.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_strap', path: 'vendor/rails_strap-1.0.2'
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What os are you running?

Comment: How large is your repo? (run `du -h .git`)

Comment: Hi @ryanbrainard 136mb.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this may be ridiculously obvious.  However, I just had this error and googled it and then ended up "fixing" it on my own.  For me I got this error because my internet connection was bad.  I reconnected and then pushed to heroku again and it worked fine.

Probably not the only solution but make sure your connection is not getting interrupted first, sometimes the simplest answer is the answer.